# Dublin transit visa

Tags: transit-visas, ireland, uk-residents, zimbabwean-citizens

I traveled from the uk to New York via Dublin without a visa , I am a uk resident with a Zimbabwean passport. I was issued a visa warning. I need to go back in 10days and I can not exactly afford another ticket. Irish visa procuring
times are 4-8weeks not sure what to do please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE.  What do you mean by "visa warning"?  Are you saying you successfully flew from London to Dublin to New York, but are now concerned they will not let you fly back the same way?

Comment: @lambshaanxy https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/143833/118049

Comment: Is the return trip taking the same route? Are both flights on single booking? Which airline(s) and flights? Have you tried to change your booking for a direct flight, or a flight through a country not requiring a transit visa (e.g. any Schengen country, in your case, as long as you can stay airside)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you will be able to even board the flight, let alone try your luck at border control, to Dublin at all since you don't have a visa for Ireland.

The visa warning doesn't matter in this case

TIMATIC states :

> Ireland (Republic of) - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> Family members of a national of an EEA Member State, Switzerland or
> the United Kingdom, with a residence permit issued by United Kingdom
> to family members of a Union Citizen. They must travel with or travel
> to join the Union Citizen. Warning
>
> All transiting passengers are subject to a check by immigration.
> Passengers in transit must hold passports or other documents accepted
> to enter Ireland (Rep.).

Comment: If OP holds a UK residence permit, and is returning to the UK to join their family member Union Citizen, wouldn't that qualify for the exemption?

Comment: @lambshaanxy TIMATIC is outdated on this one, they're surely asking about a Article 10 card

Comment: According to [Irish Immigration](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/) Zimbabwe is a transit visa-required country. No mention of exemption for UK residents/ family members as far as I can see.

Comment: @Traveller That exception doesn't exist anymore, a "family members of a Union Citizen" residence permit is an Article 10 residence card in the EU, the UK isn't a EU member and so can't issue Article 10 RC

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Yes, I agreed with your answer but as Timatic is usually correct I checked the official Irish Immigration advice to confirm. Recommend updating your answer with the link :-)

Comment: @lambshaanxy yes i am worried as I have to pass through Dublin again I don’t have time to apply for the visa in the US , it takes 4-6weeks . I’m don’t know what will happen if I try and go through there again because they issued me a visa warning

Comment: @MelodyMtisi You will **not** board the plane, airlines must check that you have a visa, you need to change your flight, I'm sorry