# How long should I stay in Ireland when granted entry without a visa and my passport stamped “Visa Warning Given”?

Tags: transit-visas, ireland

I honestly did not know that I required a visa to visit Ireland. I have a UK visa and a Biometric Resident Permit. I was asked a few questions by the immigration officer and was granted entry but my passport was stamped “Visa Warning given”. How long should I stay in Ireland? (My intended stay is 70 days) Is there anything I need to do? Will I be allowed in the UK when I go back?

Comment: Did you tell the Immigration Officer how long you plan to stay? When does your UK visa expire?

Comment: Were it to happen to me I'd assume you're supposed to leave the country at the earliest opportunity, and are allowed in just to arrange for transport out.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/143831/287

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this as "transit visa". That's what you use for a *very* short stay, i.e. where you are only in Ireland for a layover. 70 *hours* would be fairly long for a layover. 70 days is a lot longer than a typical vacation (~21 days) so you need to make sure that there are no bigger misunderstandings here.

Comment: What did the immigration officer say? Did the officer really just stamp your passeport with this "visa warning given" stamp and not explain anything?

Answer (score 13):

I would contact the Immigration Department at Burgh Quay, Dublin and ask them to clarify how long you are allowed to stay in Ireland. Otherwise I think it’s just guesswork if no Irish time limit is stamped in your passport. (They have the capacity to put appropriate stamps in your passport if that is required).

https://www.irishimmigration.ie/contact-immigration-service-delivery/